# Is Cyclic cohomology a Weil cohomology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Simply stated question...

> Is the cyclic homology theory of an algebra a Weil cohomology theory, given the appropriate reformulation of the Weil axioms?

Comment: Cyclic homology is Hochschild homology on cyclically invariant chains, and a Weil cohomology theory is a cohomology theory on a class of projective varieties which satisfies some natural set of axioms.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could make sense of this, given that cyclic homology of the base is periodic. Moreover, if you extend cyclic homology to schemes (and on quasicompact, quasiseparated schemes there is only one way to do this), then the cyclic homology of projective space is also periodic as calculated by Beckmann, so it doesn't satisfy being zero outside zero to twice the dimension.

Comment: Cool, perfect answer :D  Thanks alot Jason :)